# Multithread programming and incrementing a static variable

Tags: java, multithreading, static, locking

I have read almost all posts related to my problem but could not solve my problem. this code is a question in the Big Java - Early Object of Cay Horstmann. The question asks about counting the word of several files by using multithread programming and **store the combined words counting** which is my problem.

in order to get the combined counter I used a `static` variable  which is incremented on each of iteration of counting words in threads. Also I used a `ReentrantLock()` to make incrementing available only for one thread at a time.
everything works fine except incrementing. it seems sometimes the static variable does not incremented. I tested the number of `lock()` and `unlock()`
by each thread and they match with my expected result however the `static` variable does not work properly.

is there any explanation for it? thank you for your time and help.

my `task class`:

```
 import java.io.File;
 import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
 import java.util.Scanner;
 import java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock;
 import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

public class WordCount implements Runnable
{
    private String fileName;
    Scanner inputFile;
    private long counter;
    public volatile static long combinedCounter = 0;
    Lock ccLock;

    public WordCount(String aName) throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        try
        {
            this.ccLock = new ReentrantLock();
            this.counter = 0;
            this.fileName = aName;
            this.inputFile = new Scanner(new File(this.fileName));
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e)
        {}
     }
    public void cCount()
    {
        ccLock.lock();
        try
        {
            combinedCounter++;
            /*synchronized (this)
            {
                combinedCounter++;
            }*/
         }
        finally
        {
            ccLock.unlock();
        }
     }
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        try
        {
            while (inputFile.hasNext() && !Thread.interrupted())
            {
                 synchronized (this)
                 {
                     cCount();
                 }
                 counter++;
                 inputFile.next();
                 Thread.sleep(0);
             }
             System.out.printf("%s: %d\t\t%d\n", this.fileName,           
             this.counter,combinedCounter);
        }
         catch (InterruptedException e)
         {}
     }
 }
```

This is my `client class`:

```
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
    import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

    public class WordCountRunner
    {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException,
                InterruptedException
        {
            String a = "a.txt";
            String b = "b.txt";
            ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
            ;
            try
            {
                Runnable r1 = new WordCount(a);
                Runnable r2 = new WordCount(b);
                pool.execute(r1);
                pool.execute(r2);

                while (!pool.isTerminated())
                {
                    pool.shutdown();
                }
                Thread.sleep(100);
                System.out.print("***" + WordCount.combinedCounter);
            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException e)
            {

            }
            finally
            {
                pool.shutdown();

            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: And where is the part of the program that runs all those threads? By the way, I think you are supposed to count privately in each thread and then add the *result* to the combined data.

Comment: Why not just synchronize the static variable and don't worry about locking...

Comment: I added the client class @RealSkeptic. I am checking your solution now.

Comment: I am checking it @brso05 - Did not work.

Comment: If you're using Java 8, look at [LongAdder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/LongAdder.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The lock does not work because the ReentrantLock is an instance variable in the WordCount class.  So, each instance of that class has its own private lock and they don't synchronize with each other.  The easiest change would be to make the lock static, like the variable it's protecting.

Comment: should `Lock` be always `static`? is there any other solution?

Comment: I suggested the simplest change.  The `Lock` object should have the same object lifecycle as the object it is protecting.  Meaning, it's created and destroyed at the same time as the object it protects.  However, there are multiple ways to solve this problem.  For example, as @brso05 mentioned, you could simply `synchronize` on the static variable and achieve the same effect.

Answer (score 2):

Each of your `Runnable`s has its own lock object.  For your strategy to work, they all need to share exactly *one* lock.

For example,

```
    // ...
    static Lock ccLock = new ReentrantLock();

    public WordCount(String aName) throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        try
        {
            // this.ccLock = new ReentrantLock();
            this.counter = 0;
            this.fileName = aName;
            this.inputFile = new Scanner(new File(this.fileName));
        // ...
    }
```